# raphael behavior with jquery ui

Tags: raphael, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to use Raphael and jQuery UI. A very simple example of my problem involves a simple button which opens a jQuery dialog.

Inside that dialog I am using a Raphael paper to draw a list of texts from an array, overlaid by some transparent rectangles assigned with a click event.

I don't know how to create a jsfiddle for this example, therefore pasting my code below.

First, the html part:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div><button id="fireit">Open</button></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next, the jscode.js part:

```
$( function() {

    $("#content").dialog({
        position: {my: "left top", at: "left+5px top+40px", of: window},
        title: "A title",
        width: 350,
        height: 375,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });

    var paper_content = Raphael("content", 300, 30);
    var info = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"];

    paper_content.setStart();
    var texts = paper_content.setFinish();

    function print_texts() {
        texts.remove();
        var i;
        var row = 10;

        paper_content.setStart();

        for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            paper_content.text(25, row, info[i])
                .attr({'text-anchor': 'start', 'font-size': '14px'});
            row += 20;     
        }

        row = 10;
        var somerect;

        for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            somerect = paper_content
                .rect(5, row - 10, 500, 20)
                .attr({fill: "#acadea", 'stroke-opacity': '0.5', 'fill-opacity': 0.5});
            somerect.id = i;
            somerect.click(function() {
                alert(info[this.id]);
            })
            row += 20;
        }

        texts = paper_content.setFinish();
    }

    $("#fireit").click(function() {
        print_texts();
        $(paper_content.canvas).height(texts.getBBox().height + 20);
        $("#content").dialog("open");
    })
});
```

The click function triggers the print_texts() function, and since what Raphael printed is taller than the paper, the paper canvas gets resized.

The problem appears when firing the button: the texts printed by Raphael are not where they were supposed to be...!

A second click on the button magically arranges them in the right order.

Now the question: how can I overcome this? I need to have the correct order from the first click.

Thanks in advance for any hint,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, once obtaining a minimal example, the answer pops up by itself.
The point was to first open the dialog and only then to run the other instructions:

```
$("#fireit").click(function() {
    $("#content").dialog("open");
    print_texts();
    $(paper_content.canvas).height(texts.getBBox().height + 20);
})
```